# New playback of another video file in PyQT5 using VLC

Tags: python, pyqt, vlc, python-vlc

I am writing a script that, when launched, plays a video by its number. Then, after the end of playback, the script asks for the video number for the next playback, and so on. I use VLC python in PyQT5.

```
import sys
import time
import vlc

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Player(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Player, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")
        # creating a basic vlc instance
        self.instance = vlc.Instance(['--video-on-top'])
        self.instance.log_unset()
        
        self.media=None
        
        self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()
        
        self.create_ui()
        self.open_file()
    def create_ui(self):
        
        
        self.videoframe = QtWidgets.QFrame(
            frameShape=QtWidgets.QFrame.Box, frameShadow=QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)

        if sys.platform.startswith("linux"):  # for Linux using the X Server
            self.mediaplayer.set_xwindow(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "win32":  # for Windows
            self.mediaplayer.set_hwnd(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":  # for MacOS
            self.mediaplayer.set_nsobject(self.videoframe.winId())

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.videoframe)
        
    def play(self):
        if self.mediaplayer.play() == -1:
           self.open_file()
        self.mediaplayer.play()
    
    def open_file(self):
        numberfile = input("Number file: ")
        filename = (f"/home/Tadont/Video/{numberfile}.mp4")
        self.media = self.instance.media_new(filename)
        self.mediaplayer.set_media(self.media)
        self.eventManager=self.mediaplayer.event_manager()
        self.eventManager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.next_file)
        self.play()
        
      
    def next_file(self, event):
         if event.type == vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached:
             #self.mediaplayer.stop()
             self.open_file()
        
        

def main():   
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   player = Player()
   player.show()
   player.move(1, 1)
   player.resize(406, 86)
   player.setObjectName("MainWindow")
   player.setStyleSheet("#MainWindow{background-color:black}")
   sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I have the first file to play, then I write the file number for the second playback, but the second file does not start. How to solve this problem?

I guess I don't have a new

```
self.media
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the callback for the VLC `MediaPlayerEndReached` event will be run on a worker thread, not on the main thread. So, use the inter-thread signal mechanism or the `postEvent()`.

This is an example for the latter.

```
...
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QEvent
...
class Player(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...
    def open_file(self):
        ....
        self.eventManager=self.mediaplayer.event_manager()
        self.eventManager.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached,
            lambda _: QCoreApplication.postEvent(self, QEvent(QEvent.User))
        self.play()

    def customEvent(self, event):
        # You need to dispatch if you use custom events for other cases.
        self.open_file()
...
```